# Rails pop up at specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, timer, popup, scheduler

Is there a way to open a pop up for user at a specific time. I have mvc for events which have in DB info about when this event is starting. I want to open a pop up for the user informing him/her that the event has started. This operation will be happening often, so I don't want to use cron/whenever.

Is there a gentle way for achieving this?

Comment: "I have mvc for events which have in DB info about when this event is starting." What do you mean by that?

Comment: That I have table events, with column start_time, which indicates when should event begin.

Comment: This tutorial should help [https://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/jquery-inactivity-warning-logout-timer-setinterval-clearinterval/], time 15 mins is specified in there You can pass that value for from db for current_user

Comment: @Sontya link broken. parser thinks the trailing bracket is part of the URL

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use cron or scheduler?

Comment: Thank you Sontya I will check that out. @NickM there will be a lot of events and I am not sure if it would be okay. Thank you for your comments, I appreciate your help.